# Moshi JsonAdapter to handle Observable<Bitmap> in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, moshi

Currently, I'm decoding `Bitmap` the following way:

```
@GET("api/users/get_avatar/{userId}/default.png")
fun getAvatar(@Header("ApiToken") apiToken: String, @Path("userId") userId: String): Observable<ResponseBody>
```

and decoding it in ViewModel

```
val avatar = it()?.let { body ->
   val stream = body.byteStream()
   BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream)
}
```

However, I would like to use for that more elegant Moshi JsonAdapter.

My call looks like:

```
@GET("api/users/get_avatar/{userId}/default.png")
fun getAvatar(@Header("ApiToken") apiToken: String, @Path("userId") userId: String): Observable<Bitmap>
```

I'm adding adapter:

```
return Moshi.Builder()
        .add(BitmapAdapter())
```

However, most probably my adapter is wrong:

```
private class BitmapAdapter {

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: Bitmap): String {
        return value.encodeBase64()
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String): Bitmap {
        return value.decodeBase64()
    }
}
```

How it should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moshi is meant for parsing JSON, not directly decoding images. If you want to get a `Bitmap` from a Retrofit client, you'd want a `Converter.Factory` to supply directly to Retrofit.

Example:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Converter
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import java.lang.reflect.Type

class BitmapConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {

    override fun responseBodyConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<ResponseBody, *>? {
        return if (type == Bitmap::class.java) {
            Converter<ResponseBody, Bitmap> {
                value -> BitmapFactory.decodeStream(value.byteStream())
            }
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

And supply it wherever you instantiate your Retrofit instance:

```
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://myapi.com")
    .addConverterFactory(BitmapConverterFactory())
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
```

Edit: I initially made a mistake in `BitmapCoverterFactory`. The comparison of `type` was initially against `Bitmap::javaClass`, it should be `Bitmap::class.java`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting 

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform class android.graphics.Bitmap (with no annotations) requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered
        at com.squareup.moshi.ClassJsonAdapter$1.create(ClassJsonAdapter.java:60)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:137)
        at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:97)`

when adding `BitmapConverterFactory`

Comment: @qbait The order is important. When you instantiate your Retrofit instance with the builder, the `BitmapConverterFactory` should come _before_ the `MoshiConverterFactory`. Otherwise the Moshi converter factory will try to take over.

Comment: @qbait I also made a mistake in `BitmapConverterFactory`, I updated it in the answer.

Comment: Perfect, it works with 2 small changes: `Bitmap::class.java` instead of `BufferedImage::class.java` and I needed to add types to Converter `Converter<ResponseBody, Bitmap>`. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Oh sorry! I was doing an example on my machine in pure Kotlin (no Android) so I was using BufferedImage instead of Bitmap. Glad it worked!